# How to subset the string by escaping some characters

Tags: r, regex, substring

I want to subset the string in two sub-string in following way

1. select character from 5 to 20
2. select character from 5 to 21 but escape the 20th character

Example:

```
String: AGGTGAACGCCACGTCCAAAGTTAGGTGATGCATTCAAGTT
sub1: GAACGCCACGTCCAAA
sub2: GAACGCCACGTCCAAG
```

Comment: How is this too broad? The fact the question generated 2 answers giving the exact desired result pretty much proves it isn't.

Comment: If anything it's too **narrow**. Voted reopen.

Comment: and then down-arrowed for "does not show any research effort". Did you look for tutorials on string handling in R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `sub` to match the first 4 characters `(.{4}`) from the start (`^`) of the string followed by the next 16 which we capture as a group (`(.{16})`) followed by other characters (`.*`) and replace it with the backreference (`\\1`) of the captured grouop

```
sub("^.{4}(.{16}).*", "\\1", str1)
#[1] "GAACGCCACGTCCAAA"
```

We can get the first case with `substr/substring`

```
substr(str1, 5, 20)
#[1] "GAACGCCACGTCCAAA"
```

For the second case, instead of capturing 16 characters, capture 15 characters followed by a character (`.`)  followed by capturing the next character as a group (`(.)`) and replace with the backreferences (`\\1\\2`) of the captured group

```
sub("^.{4}(.{15}).(.).*", "\\1\\2", str1)
#[1] "GAACGCCACGTCCAAG"
```

Or with `substr`

```
sprintf("%s%s", substr(str1, 5, 19), substr(str1, 21, 21))
#[1] "GAACGCCACGTCCAAG"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "AGGTGAACGCCACGTCCAAAGTTAGGTGATGCATTCAAGTT"
```

Answer (score 4):

The `?substring` function is also useful. It is distinct from `?substr`, by its capability to handle single or multiple substrings at once:

```
substring(str1, 5, 20)
#[1] "GAACGCCACGTCCAAA"

substring(str1, c(5,21), c(19,21))
#[1] "GAACGCCACGTCCAA" "G" 

paste(substring(str1, c(5,21), c(19,21)), collapse="")
#[1] "GAACGCCACGTCCAAG"
```

Comment: Keep in mind though that when `str1` is multiple strings, the result won't be what you want. Because `substring` doesn't really select multiple substrings, it just recycles all its arguments (which `substr` doesn't).